# How can I copy values from one dataframe column to another based on the difference between the values

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dask

I have two csv  mirror files generated by two different servers. Both files have the same number of lines and should have the exact same unix timestamp column. However, due to some clock issues, some records in one file, might have asmall  difference of a nanosecond than it's counterpart record in the other csv file, see below an example, the difference is always of 1:

```
dataframe_A                                          dataframe_B

|          | ts_ns              |            |          | ts_ns              |
| -------- | ------------------ |            | -------- | ------------------ |
| 1        | 1661773636777407794|            | 1        | 1661773636777407793|
| 2        | 1661773636786474677|            | 2        | 1661773636786474677|
| 3        | 1661773636787956823|            | 3        | 1661773636787956823|
| 4        | 1661773636794333099|            | 4        | 1661773636794333100|
```

Since these are huge files with milions of lines, I use pandas and dask to process them, but before I process, I need to ensure they have the same timestamp column.
I need to check the difference between column ts_ns in A and B and if there is a difference of 1 or -1 I need to replace the value in B with the corresponding ts_ns value in A so I can finally have the same ts_ns value in both files for corresponding records.

How can I do this in a decent way using pandas/dask?

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that the timestamps should be identical, why don't you simply use the timestamp column from dataframe A and overwrite the timestamp column in dataframe B with it?

Why even check whether the difference is there or not?

Comment: That's exactly what I did, unfortunately the solution was not accepted by the team and manager since they insist there might be records with significant timestamp difference , and it would break the data joins I do later in the processing since I use ts_ns among the key columns.  You see, even though these are mirror files, a couple of columns are different between them so I have to create a union of these records based on a multi column key(It s complicated).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pandas merge_asof function for this, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html . The `tolerance` allows for a int or timedelta which should be set to the +1 for your example with `direction` being `nearest`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your files are identical except from your `ts_ns` column you can perform a `.merge` on indices.

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame({'ts_ns': [1661773636777407794, 1661773636786474677, 1661773636787956823, 1661773636794333099]})
df_b = pd.DataFrame({'ts_ns': [1661773636777407793, 1661773636786474677, 1661773636787956823, 1661773636794333100]})

df_b = (df_b
    .merge(df_a, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=('', '_a'))
    .assign(
        ts_ns = lambda df_: np.where(abs(df_.ts_ns - df_.ts_ns_a) <= 1, df_.ts_ns_a, df_.ts_ns)
    )
    .loc[:, ['ts_ns']]
)
```

But I agree with @ManEngel, just overwrite all the values if you know they are identical.